# Flink Job on EMR with typesafe config as dependency gives NoSuchMethodError: Config.getEnum

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-flink, amazon-emr, flink-streaming

I have a flink Job (Running on AWS EMR) which uses another maven dependency and that dependency uses **Typesafe Config**, the job runs fine on local machine but it gives below error while running on AWS EMR

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.typesafe.config.Config.getEnum(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Enum;
```

Can someone help resolve this issue? Is it something to do with default flink EMR setup ?